# "stick to broad strokes"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I read such a following sentence:

> Whenever you’re tackling a new project, it can be tempting to dive right into writing code. But more often than not, it’s best to take a step back and consider the bigger picture. I recommend first drawing up a high-level plan for what your program needs to do. Don’t think about the actual code yet— you can worry about that later. Right now, **stick to broad strokes**.

I looked it in [Broad strokes](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/broad+strokes)

> **broad stroke** or broad brushstrokes 
>   If you describe or show something in broad strokes or in broad brushstrokes, you describe or show only the main or general points or features of it and not the fine or exact details.
>   Vague or non-specific terms.

So "Right now, stick to broad strokes" roughly means "do it from a bird-view".

However, I am confuse with "stick to",
I might get an idea if say "We should constantly stick to broad strokes in advance", nonetheless, "Right now, stick to", I don's understand it entirely.

How do I understand "stick to broad strokes"?

Comment: Can you link or include the reference, the source of your sentence? It's an interesting data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Cambridge Dictionary

**[stick](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick)**

> **to cause something to become fixed**, for example with glue or another similar substance

I have highlighted the meaning. In your context it's a metaphor, you don't have to glue yourself to a brush. Sorry for the joke. You have to **maintain your focus** in the bigger picture, **fix** your attention, determine clearly what your software has to do and how you structure its functionalities and their relations, the architecture, before implementing anything.

Answer (score 2):

"Stick to" means roughly "only do something this way". So here, it's saying "only do the broad strokes stuff", that is, "only do the big-picture part, where you get an idea of what you want your program to do in general, and don't start thinking about the details."

Comment: Another way to say "stick to" would be "limit yourself to".